# How to prove the existence of N in natural numbers in a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let  $a_n$ be a convergent sequence of integers.

Prove that the limit of the sequence is an integer.

I've tried using the $ε − N$  definition of the limit, but have no idea how to proceed. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to prove?  A convergent sequence of integers has to be constant eventually...is that what you are asking?

Comment: As written, your question is not clear.  Can you edit it for clarity?  If not, I think the question will soon be closed.

Comment: Thanks for the editing! Makes it clearer what I want to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_k$ be a convergent sequence of integers. Then $\forall\epsilon>0\exists N$ such that $n>N\Rightarrow|a_n-L|<\epsilon$ where $L$ is the limit of the sequence.

Assume that $L$ is not an integer. Let $d$ be the distance to the nearest integer (by discreetness this is well defined and non-zero). Then for $\epsilon <d$ there doesn't exist any integers within $\epsilon$ of $L$, So a sequence of integers cannot converge to $L$.

Comment: Thank you. Really helped me out.